# redirect page based on country and context path

Tags: apache, request-uri

```
  If the request_uri is starting with "^/country/location/London/" then any thing after "/country/location/London/(.*)" should redirect to "/$1" and fetch the data from back-end for "/country/location/London/$1"
```

Tried some rules as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/country/location/london/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1.html [NC,L,PT] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/country/location/germany/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1.html [NC,L,PT]
```

Comment: Use `RewriteRule`.  If this is all the redirections you need, you are basically saying "everything with home.html at the end goes to www.example.com/home.html".  Do some research, we can help if you are stuck **after you try** on your own.

Comment: Updated with proper details Now :)